# angular 4 Drop Down Menu Setting Selected State

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, selected, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I am working on an angular 4 web app. I am trying to set the initial selected state of a drop down menu. No matter what I do though the initial selected state of the drop down menu is not being set. See my html below ( am trying to set the healthy option of a recipe to either be 'yes' or 'no', depending what is brought back from the database:-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form [formGroup]="update_recipe_form" (ngSubmit)="createUpdateRecipeIngredientsDetailsForm()">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">

          <tr>
            <td>
              Healthy
            </td>
            <td><!--<li *ngIf="recipe?.healthy == 'Yes'"><h4><i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>Healthy</h4></li>-->
              <select name="isHealthy" formControlName="isHealthy" class="form-control" required>
                <option *ngFor="let healthy of healthyOptionsArray" [selected]="isHealthy==healthy.state" value="{{healthy.id}}">
                  {{healthy.state}}
                </option>
              </select>
              <div *ngIf="update_recipe_form.get('isHealthy').touched && update_recipe_form.get('isHealthy').hasError('required')"
                  class="alert alert-danger">Select whether recipe is healthy
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="update_recipe_form.invalid">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Typescript module code:-

```
import { Component, Output, Input, EventEmitter, OnChanges, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { Healthy } from '../healthy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-recipe',
  templateUrl: './update-recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-recipe.component.css'],
  providers: [RecipeService, CategoryService, DifficultyService, ImageService, IngredientService, IngredientDetailService ]
})
export class UpdateRecipeComponent {

  @Output() show_read_recipes_event = new EventEmitter();

  @Input() recipe_id;

  update_recipe_form: FormGroup;

   healthyOptionsArray = [
    new Healthy(0, 'no'),
    new Healthy(1, 'yes')
  ]

  constructor(private _recipeService: RecipeService, 
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private elem: ElementRef
  )         
  { 
    // build angular form
    this.update_recipe_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      recipe_name: ["", Validators.required],
      recipe_id: '',
      isHealthy: ["", Validators.required],
    });
  }

  readRecipes(){
    this.show_read_recipes_event.emit({ title: "Read Recipes"});
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this._recipeService.readOneRecipeForUpdate(this.recipe_id)
      .subscribe(
        recipe => {
          console.log(recipe);
          this.update_recipe_form.patchValue({
            recipe_name: recipe.recipe_name,
            recipe_id: recipe.recipe_id,
            isHealthy: recipe.healthy,
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

This is the Healthy class code:-

```
export class Healthy{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public state: string
    )
    {}
}
```

Hope somebody can put me out of my misery (I have been stuck on this one for a few days now).

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(recipe);`?

Comment: Check this out https://ng-run.com/edit/w81R0thzFmtdEV2M9jQZ

Answer (score 1):

You can change:

```
[selected]="isHealthy==healthy.state"
```

to:

```
[selected]="healthy.state === 'yes'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting object value exactly same that of `healthy` object of iterator, then use `ngValue` directive to bind whole object value to form. It will help to pre-populate value.

```
<select name="isHealthy" formControlName="isHealthy" class="form-control" required>
  <option *ngFor="let healthy of healthyOptionsArray" [ngValue]="healthy">
      {{healthy.state}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or you can directly bind it to `value`

Comment: @ArjunPanicker `value` attribute will not store object binding, `ngValue` directive have been made to handle such case..

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<select name="isHealthy" formControlName="isHealthy" class="form-control" required>
  <option *ngFor="let healthy of healthyOptionsArray" [selected]="healthy.state == isHealthy">
    {{healthy.state}}
   </option>
 </select>
```